# Enabling and Disabling buttons in html alternatively

Tags: javascript, java, html, frontend

When user open the page, the Update button must be disable and Edit button should be enable and there should be no chance to edit the text fields.

When user clicks on Edit button, the Update button must be enable and Edit button should be disable and the user able to edit only `FirstName` and `LastName` but he should not able to do edit the `EmpId` field.
Please help me in this.

**This is some part of my code:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function func1(){
    document.getElementById("update").disabled=true;
  }
  function btnUpdate(){
    if(document.getElementById("edit").clicked=true;){
        document.getElementById("update").disabled=false;
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body  onload="func1()">
  <table rules="all" border="" style="position: absolute;left: 337px;top: 125px;">
    <tr><td id="EmpID">EmpID:</td><td><input type="text" value="MGIS107"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="FirstName">FirstName:</td><td><input type="text" value="Vikas"></td></tr>
    <tr><td id="LastName">LastName:</td><td><input type="text" value="Dubbaka"></td></tr>
    <input type="button" value="Update" id="update">
    &nbsp;
    <input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit" onclick="btnUpdate()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use attributes like readonly and dynamically remove the based on the condition that you mentioned. I don't see what would be difficult here. Any specific issue you are facing with?

Comment: Remember, that doing stuff like that is only to make it pretty for the user;  You will need to validate server side that the "EmpId" has not been changed.

Comment: if i write one function then im getting Update button disable, when i write onclick function for Edit button then, both buttons are enabled.

Comment: @Mikkel Bachamann I'm a beginner, the task given to me is to do only client side.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

```js
var empId = document.getElementById("EmpID");
var fName = document.getElementById("FirstName");
var lName = document.getElementById("LastName");
empId.disabled = true;
function func1(){
    document.getElementById("update").disabled = true;
    fName.disabled = true;
    lName.disabled = true;
}
function btnUpdate(el){
  document.getElementById("update").disabled = false;
  el.disabled = true;
  fName.disabled = false;
  lName.disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<body  onload="func1()">
  <table rules="all" border="" style="position: absolute;left: 337px;top: 125px;">
  <tr><td>EmpID:</td><td><input type="text" id="EmpID" value="MGIS107"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>FirstName:</td><td><input type="text" id="FirstName" value="Vikas"></td></tr>
  <tr><td>LastName:</td><td><input type="text" id="LastName" value="Dubbaka"></td></tr>
  <input type="button" value="Update" id="update">
  &nbsp;
  <input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit" onclick="btnUpdate(this)">
  </table>
</body>
```